# UWP Popup class bug

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created a simple notepad. I am unable to assign a User Control to the Child property of Popup. Every time I do it throws an exception of type System.ArgumentException. When I instantiate the User Control in code it works fine.

User control is called WrapOptionsDialog.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:WrapOptionsDialog x:Key="wrapOptionsDialog" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="txtbox"
             IsEnabled="False"
             FontSize="24"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             TextWrapping="{Binding Source={StaticResource wrapOptionsDialog}, Path=TextWrapping, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>

WrapOptionsDialog wrapOptionsDialog = this.Resources["wrapOptionsDialog"] as WrapOptionsDialog;

// Create popup
Popup popup = new Popup
{
    Child = wrapOptionsDialog,
    IsLightDismissEnabled = true,
};
```

Below in comment I'm going to link the actual project. Exception occurs after clicking on Wrap Option button. Please help.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgdgTvs5s5ouhyngveosAuuRoEOx?e=wK2By2

Comment: Popup is a lazy loading mode, and its context is not on the page, so if you use the xaml way to create wrapoptionsDialog, when it try to find wrapoptionsDialog, the lookup may go wrong, because their contexts are not consistent. So it is better to use the `new WrapOptionsDialog();` way to create in code-behind.